# gwt-maven-plugin runs permutations even when there are no changes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, plugins

We are using GWT in our product with mojo gwt-maven-plugin 2.4 to compile the GWT code.
But we observed that when we run mvn install, the gwt maven plugin is running the permutations even when no code changes are made to GWT code.
After struggling on this issue for quite some time, we were able to reproduce it with a simple setup using 2 maven projects:

- **1st project(MyGwtMavenSampleSource)** : Contains the GWT code along with the gwt module xml file
- **2nd project (MavenBuilderMod)**: Contains the MyGwtMavenSampleSource as maven dependency and will build the war
  file.

Below are the poms for both the projects:

**1st Project: MyGwtMavenSampleSource**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>GWTMavenPlugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyGwtMavenSampleSource</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

  <properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**2nd Project: MavenBuilderMod**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org    /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>GWTMavenPlugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenBuilderMod</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>GWTMavenPlugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>MyGwtMavenSampleSource</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>src-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <classifier>sources</classifier>
                  <failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>false</failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/sources</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
      <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see 
          gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
        <configuration>
          <runTarget>MyGwtMavenSampleSource.html</runTarget>
          <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
          <modules>
            <module>com.ca.gwt.maven.sample.MyGwtMavenSampleSource</module>
        </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

So, the question is, how can we make gwt-maven-plugin / compiler to run the permutations only on code change in this kind of setup.

---

Note: This works as expected (i.e permutations are run only when the code is changed) if gwt module xml file is placed in the same maven module that contains the gwt-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

The root issue is Maven's broken support for incremental builds, and possibly broken incremental-build support in the gwt-maven-plugin (particularly if you're still using a more-than-2-year-old version!).

The gwt-maven-plugin somehow sees that the gwt.xml file has changed (track the build of your first module, ideally it should really be a no-op if nothing changed; re-copying the resources and/or rebuilding the JAR would probably be enough to trigger the issue downwards), and particularly is more recent than the nocache.js file it produced.

I think a better setup is to run the gwt-maven-plugin in the first module and package everything in a ZIP or WAR, that you can then use as a WAR overlay. It unfortunately makes running DevMode a bit harder, but [it's workable](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes).